# SSL with runtime certs Java

Tags: java, ssl, runtime

I have a java project in which in each installation there is a server and a client. The connection should be secured. The server part is to be cross-platform (including Android), so using Keytool or openssl for key generation is not an option.

As there will be lots of servers I cannot just generate one cert and include it, because then every server would have the same certificate (of course, self-signed).

So ideally I want to have the certificate generated at runtime when the server starts the first time, using pure java, as I cannot use any external tools.

Please provide an example of the actual implementation. Alternative methods or suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: "As there will be lots of servers I cannot just generate one cert and include it, because then every server would have the same certificate" - Why would that be a problem?

Comment: Both server and client are to be freely downloaded, so anybody would have access to the private key of the client.

Comment: Having a server generate its own certificate provides absolutely zero security to the clients. You need to rethink your requirement: it is radically insecure. And nobody is going to give you an example of an actual implementation. That's your job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something like what you want.

```
//Build a blank keystore with a password
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
char[] password = "some password".toCharArray();
ks.load(null, password);

//Sample key storage
javax.crypto.SecretKey mySecretKey;
KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry skEntry =
    new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(mySecretKey);
ks.setEntry("secretKeyAlias", skEntry, 
    new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password));

//Update the keystore file
fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream("keystorefilename");
ks.store(fos, password);
```

However,  you'll need to use BouncyCastle to create the certificate and import it however. There's [a tutorial on that available](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/BC+Version+2+APIs).

Answer (score 1):

This question reading also the comments does not make much sense.
Even if you generated a keystore on the fly on first installation (which is something possible e.g. via Bouncy Castle) you would need to store it in the filesystem for next restart.
If clients are to authenticate the server, they would need to receive the same certificate as the one they have in their truststore (and not a newly generated one on each restart as per your OP) which is the difficult part in your case since you are not using a certificate of a well knowing issuer and would have to *manually* import the trusted certificate to the client's truststore.

Comment: Exactly so. The requirement is radically insecure. The server installers need to generate their own certificates.